# How to load a component from a button click in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, onclicklistener, link-to

I'm creating a simple react app. I need to load a component from a button click. When I click the `edit` button I need to load the edit component. I tried it using `<Link>`. But I can't understand how to give the relative path. It means it need to load it like `http://localhost:3002/viewTicket/603c9a02a2ccd501f45f820e/edit`. I need to load it from `http://localhost:3002/viewTicket/603c9a02a2ccd501f45f820e`. How can I give the relative path?

**App.js**

```
<Provider store={configureStore()}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <LayoutWrapper>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
              <Route path="/viewTicket/:id" exact component={ViewTicket} />
              <Route path="/viewTicket/:id/edit" exact component={EditTicket} />
            </Switch>
          </LayoutWrapper>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
```

**Ticket.js**

```
                       <Link to="/viewTicket/:id/edit">
                          <Button size="lg" onClick={this.handleEdit}>
                            <Pencil />
                            &nbsp; Edit
                          </Button>
                        </Link>
```

[image]
But url lokks like this.
Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I edited the question.I added a picture.Can you please look into that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to include the actual ID in the URL.  You're just directing the user to this literal string that has ":id" in it:

```
<Link to="/viewTicket/:id/edit">
```

Whatever your ID values is (for demonstration let's assume it's in a variable called `id`), you'd use that to build your URL:

```
<Link to={`/viewTicket/${id}/edit`}>
```

---

As an aside, this is a very strange structure and will likely lead to confusion:

```
<Link to="/viewTicket/:id/edit">
  <Button size="lg" onClick={this.handleEdit}>
```

Putting a button inside of a link means that you're trying to simultaneously do two different things.  Should `this.handleEdit` be invoked?  Or should the user be redirected by the link?  It's best to invoke a single operation.  If some logic needs to happen inside of `this.handleEdit` *before* redirecting the user, then remove the `<Link>` and manually redirect the user (likely using the `useHistory` hook) after performing that logic.

Comment: yeah I need to remove this onClick function.Thank you very much.